# boost websocket and io_context reusability for reestablishability of a connection

Tags: c++, boost, websocket, beast-websockets

I have writted a small `websocket` client using `boost::beast::websocket` and `boost::asio::io_context` in `C++`. I am having a state machine with following states:

```
enum class State {
    GDR_PROVISING,
    WEBSOCKET_HANDSHAKE,
    REGISTRATION,
    READY,
    CLEANUP,
};
```

If the code is unable to set-up a connection or fails after a connection is established (possible reasons: Internet is down, Service is down, Server sends a close frame), then the state machine moves towards `CLEANUP` state and should do the cleanup.

I am not sure if I can reuse the same `io_context` and `websocket::stream`. Currently, my io_context is only used in this single thread. I am planning to use `pointers` of websockets and io_context and delete them in CLEANUP and allocate them again in GDR_PROVISING.

**Can I use same websocket and io_context instance for reestablishing the connecction to the server? May be I need to call some member functions like `stop` or `reset`?**

My `READY` looks like this now:

```
    case State::READY:
    {
        // TODO: Send the Message from the vector
        {
            std::lock_guard<std::mutex> msgGaurd(msgMutex_);
            for (const auto& m: sendMsgQueue_) {
                boost::system::error_code ec;
                pWebStream_->write(boost::asio::buffer(m.toString()), ec);
            }
        }
        // Call io_context run_until to process read messages async because there is no way for non-blocking read in boost for websockets!
        pIoc_->run_until(std::chrono::steady_clock::now() + /* TODO: Add some time_point */);
        break;
    }

    case State::CLEANUP:
    {
        // TODO: Verify if we should delete the stream!
        if (pWebStream_)
            delete pWebStream_;
        if (pIoc_)
            delete pIoc_;
        pWebStream_ = nullptr;
        pIoc_ = nullptr;
        state_ = State::GDR_PROVISING;
        break;
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

You can reuse `io_context` as normal. The call to run wont terminate unless there is no more work left to do when it tries to do another event loop iteration.

You also can reuse the socket using `get_lowest_layer(*pWebStream_).close()`, reopening it with `get_lowest_layer(*pWebStream_).open()`, and calling `async_connect` as normal. But, I think your code would be cleaner by completely resetting the object like you do.

If you do want to reset the socket, I highly recommend you try using `std::optional`. It makes no heap allocations, and you don't have to worry about leaking memory.